# powerPoint 2013 save as picture

Tags: .net, ms-office, powerpoint

I want to simulate right click save as picture in VB.NET for powerPoint 2013,

shape.export method is not working with me, I think this was working in old versions of office,

any hint?

Comment: "not working" covers a lot of ground.  If you want a better chance of getting help, post the code that's not working, indicate exactly where it fails and quote any error messages you see.

Comment: export method is not a member in PowerPoint.shape class

Comment: It's hidden.  It's accessible in VBA if you select Show Hidden Members in the object browser of the IDE.  Perhaps VB.NET has something similar.

Comment: I don't think so @SteveRindsberg ,after some investigations I think my best try will be to rename the .pptx file to .zip then get the image files from the media folder but the question is are they sorted with the same sequence ,or how I can link them with the presentation sequence ??

Comment: If you're after images that have been inserted into the PPT, unzipping will get you there, but if you want to export ANY shape or shapes as images, unzipping won't help.  I don't recall offhand how the images are named w/in the PPTX/ZIP but as I remember, it wasn't too hard to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Copy and rename pptx file**

```
 Dim file As String = "..........\Text_Boxes_Set_1.pptx"
        Dim copy As String = "......\test1copy.zip"

        If System.IO.File.Exists(file) = True Then
            System.IO.File.Copy(file, copy)
            MsgBox("file,coppied")
        End If
```

**Extract zip file**

```
 Dim sc As New Shell32.Shell()
        'Create directory in which you will unzip your files .
        IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(".....")
        'Declare the folder where the files will be extracted
        Dim output As Shell32.Folder = sc.NameSpace(".....")
        'Declare your input zip file as folder  .
        Dim input As Shell32.Folder = sc.NameSpace("........\test1copy.zip")
        'Extract the files from the zip file using the CopyHere command .
        output.CopyHere(input.Items, 4)
```

**Get image files out of extracted folders**

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory("......\ppt\media", ".....\testimages1", True)
```